# Why I cant add my executable to windows register?

Tags: python, python-3.x, registry

I wrote this code to convert python script to exe then add the exe to register so the program can run after every bootup

```
    def add_to_startup(): # to add the program to startup
        shutil.copyfile(sys.executable,location)
        subprocess.call(r'reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v update /t REG_SZ /d "' + location + '"',shell =True)# to add your EXE to register
        print("completed")
add_to_startup()
```

when I run it as python the function works but when I convert it to exe it won't

Comment: Things like these probably would require you to run the file as Administrator.

Comment: @KimKakanAndersson the code worked, but when I added the pyautogui library so that the program moves my mouse randomly, it didint work. I think this is a security measurement, not an error in the code.right?

Comment: I've done similiar, mouseclicks and simulated keyboard clicks in Java.. That worked as long as I ran it as Admin.
In my case, I started Powershell as Admin, and ran it from there, then it worked.

Comment: So I should start it in PowerShell to work?

Answer (score 0):

So my solution to my problem was that I used .pyw as a way to hide console but this file type did a lot of problems, so first you have to use .py only. then make sure that the register is not duplicated cause if it was the CMD  will ask do you want to overwrite the register and as you dont have the console window  you wont have any way to answer this question and the program will stuck.